# Getting an error when trying to use the Controls() function on an access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to build an SQL insert statement from several form control values in access.

I've read that I could use the Controls() function to dynamically reference my controls.

I've tried to do this:

```
   Private Sub InsertCoeff(ByVal prov As String, ByVal region As String)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim insertSQL As String
    Dim valuesSQL As String
    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO 'Coefficient de Fermage'"
    valuesSQL = "("
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & "('1F','2F')"
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ",('" & Me.Controls(prov & region & "Lbl") & "','" & Me.Controls(prov & region & "Lbl") & "')"
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ",('" & Me.Controls(prov & "Lbl") & "','" & Me.Controls(prov & "Lbl") & "')"
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ",('" & Me.Controls(prov & region & "Terres") & "','" & Me.Controls(prov & "Bat") & "')"
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ",('" & Me.DateEff & "','" & Me.DateEff & "')"
    valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ")"
    strSQL = insertSQL & " VALUES " & valuesSQL
End Sub
```

But I get a runtime error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) even though vba auto-suggests the Controls() method when I start typing "Me."

Any idea why this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing labels, so the correct syntax is

```
valuesSQL = valuesSQL & ",('" & Me.Controls(prov & region & "Lbl").Caption & "','" & Me.Controls(prov & region & "Lbl").Caption & "')"
```